# Image conversion using for each

Tags: vb.net, image, converters

I am trying to do convert all .png files in a directory to .ico using VB.Net

```
   Dim DI As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(PNGFolderConverter.Text)
        Dim Files As System.IO.FileInfo() = DI.GetFiles("*.png")
        For Each Fl As System.IO.FileInfo In Files
            Dim i As Integer
            i += 1

            Dim SourceImg As Image
            SourceImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Files)
            SourceImg.Save(PNGSaveDir.Text & "\" & i.ToString & ".ico", ImageFormat.Icon)

        Next
```

But I cannot get it to work... I'm either getting an error or just getting syntax errors.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: It would help if you posted the error messages you are getting.

Comment: Specifically with this code I am getting a syntax error in this line:  SourceImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Files)

Comment: This syntax error: value of type '1-dimensional array of System.IO.FileInfo' cannot be converted to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name) and use the loop variable `Fl` rather than `Files`

```
Dim DI As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(PNGFolderConverter.Text)
Dim Files As System.IO.FileInfo() = DI.GetFiles("*.png")
For Each Fl As System.IO.FileInfo In Files
    Dim i As Integer
    i += 1

    Dim SourceImg As Image
    SourceImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Fl.Name)
    SourceImg.Save(PNGSaveDir.Text & "\" & i.ToString & ".ico", ImageFormat.Icon)

Next
```

Comment: I'm constantly getting a: FileNotFoundException

Comment: Set up breakpoints and see exactly the filepath that your code is trying to look for the png files.

Comment: Got it! I found the problem :) I will post the code with the solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim DI As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(PNGFolderConverter.Text)
        Dim Files As System.IO.FileInfo() = DI.GetFiles("*.png")
        For Each Fl As System.IO.FileInfo In Files
            Dim i As Integer
            i += 1

            Dim SourceImg As Image
            SourceImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(PNGFolderConverter.Text & "\" & Fl.Name)
            SourceImg.Save(PNGSaveDir.Text & "\" & i.ToString & ".ico", ImageFormat.Icon)

        Next
```

Here this worked.

Except the "Fl.Name" I also had to add the save directory and a "\".